# coloured text isn't shown in program

Tags: python, text

The text is meant to be coloured, however, it doesn't appear coloured after i convert the .py file to an exe. Any help would be appreciated as i have tried many other solutions.

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
colorama.init()


text = ("""                                                                            
 
                  $$$$$\                                                            
                  \__$$ |                                                              
                     $$ |     $$$$$$\$$$$\       $$$$$$\       $$$$$$$\            
                     $$ |     $$  _$$  _$$\      \____$$\     $$  _____|       
               $$\   $$ |     $$ / $$ / $$ |     $$$$$$$ |    $$ /                
               $$ |  $$ |     $$ | $$ | $$ |    $$  __$$ |    $$ |              
               \$$$$$$  |     $$ | $$ | $$ |    \$$$$$$$ |    \$$$$$$$\         
                \______/      \__| \__| \__|     \_______|     \_______|      
              
____________________________________________________________         
""")

faded = ''
red = 100
for line in text.splitlines():
    faded += (f"\033[38;2;{red};0;220m{line}\033[0m\n")
    if not red == 255:
        red += 15
        if red > 255:
            red = 255
print (faded)
```

Comment: Which terminal are you using?

Comment: It doesn't print in color for me in Windows Command Prompt nor Git Bash; It does print in color for me in PyCharm.  I don't see any color gradient, if that's the goal though.  It could be because I'm color blind.

Comment: Which tool do you use to convert the .py to .exe? Reading how colorama works on Windows platform, it has to strip out the ANSI colour code chars and replace them with win32 api calls https://github.com/tartley/colorama ...I guess that part is getting lost in the exe translation somehow